# How to upload data from SQLite to server in background when it will connect to Internet

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have certain set of records(data) in SQLite My aim is to upload a records(data) to server when it connects to internet and it should upload records(data) without notifying to user, And It should not upload same data twice. Now i am able to upload as soon as new data will arrive using AsyncTask.

I want to know, how the logic will works. Any suggestions or working example will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BroadCastReceiver` for get notified when connecting to internet.

Register your `BroadCastReciever` in activity for getting wifi state changed notification or you can register a receiver in manifest.

```
private void registerReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

for checking internet connection you can use the following class ,

```
public class CheckConnectivity {
    private Context _context;

    public CheckConnectivity(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
        if (isConnectingToInternet()) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(Constants.INTERNET_CONNECTION_URL).openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```